# How to combine symmetrized tensor expressions into single expression in xAct

Tags: xact, field-theory

Let's sayI have the following expression in xAct
[image]

where covariant derivatives are commutative, $\epsilon$ and $h$ are symmetric tensors.

As we can see this expression is equivalent to

[image]

If we symmetrize it with respect to indices $i,j,k,l$

Is there any way to express the first expression like the second one with some sort of SymmetryGroup attached to it?

Comment: Can you add how did you define the tensors h and epsilon? Did you add their symmetry there? It's important that you provide full, reproducible code.